# IOS Web Service Recommendations

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, web-services, ios

I have a MYSQL server setup. What are my option for developing a IOS web server that will allow me to do CRUD with the IOS devices.

Please help it will greatly be appreciated. This my first stackoverflow post, being getting recommendations to join this site..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend an Apache2/PHP/MySQL stack for developing a web service for use with an iOS application. Consider using one of the common PHP frameworks such as codeIgnitor or cakePHP and sending your output in JSON format (not SOAP -- too much overhead).

Comment: Gonna do some research on it so, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Do you have any examples @ Casey Flynn...

Comment: Also: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

Answer (score 2):

PHP with a framework (as mentioned by Casey) and Ruby on Rails are probably the two most common solutions -- lots of resources for both here on SO

Answer (score 1):

RobyOnRails absolutely! Because you can use RESTful web services with ease, and there is great [RESTKit](http://restkit.org/) objective-c framework for object-mapping and abstract layer for network requests.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't used this, I'm fan of http://getfrapi.com/ it is right tool for the job.